# Example on Making rest call to Python server using angular js client

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, angularjs, rest

Can anybody give an example on using rest in getting and posting data from/to python server using Angularjs .
Please provide an example for both client(angularjs) and server(python) ..
where my sample client-side code is

```
var student_id = 12
$http({
    method:"POST" // or get
    url:       //url to the python file 
    data:     //this is what confusing me .. how to send that student id 

}).success(function(data){
     console.log(data);
   })
```

and in python i want to run a function which prints student id

```
def print_info(id):   ## here id is the student id that shall be recieved
  print "student id is %s" %id
```

here i want the js client to send that student_id value to python server where it should receive it and send that value of print_info function to the client..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
$http.post('<your_url>', data).success(function(data) {
    //handle the data returned
}, function(error) {
    //handle if an error is thrown
})
```

And the format of your data can be a json like this:

```
data = {
    "student_id": value
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. for showing me how to use it in client but can you also show me how to recieve this value in python server ?

Comment: are you using any framework? can you do a 'print request' in your method.

Comment: no i'm not using any frame work on server side .the python code is just having some functions to be called by client.

Comment: try sending the value as a parameter to your method.